# Error Code 1 in FileTransfer while downloading

Tags: android, ionic2, file-transfer

Need help in the error code. I am trying to download an image from a source server(just an image from some website) . Always getting error code 1 in file transfer. I know error code 1 means file not found. But the file is available . Please find my code and error i got.

```
public downloadImage() {

   var url = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/mountain/mountain-04.jpg";


  var targetPath = '/assets/Images/menucategory/';


  const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();


  fileTransfer.download(url,targetPath + 'file.jpg' )

.then(data => 

{
    this.presentToast('Image succesful downloaded.');
  },

 err => {
  console.log('download error source', err.source);

  console.log('download error targer', err.target);

  console.log('download error code', err.code);

  console.log('download error ', err);

    this.presentToast('Error while downloading file.');
  });
}
```

Error Details:

body:null
code:1
exception:null
http_status:null
source:"http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/mountain/mountain-04.jpg"
target:"/assets/Images/menucategory/file.jpg"

Comment: `FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR: 1`  as you can see in this document https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/ if you are reciving `code:1` then it means that the file that you are trying to download is not in the server

Comment: the file is available in the server, when i paste the same source  url in the postman or any browser  i am able to see the image

Comment: @MohamedAfzal were you able to get a solution?